# React Native Saving Input Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to have two text fields:

- one that accepts a title
- another that accepts a body (i.e. more text)

...and a submit button:

- that saves the title and body that was entered, when clicked

I have researched **TextInput**, **AsyncStorage**, TouchableHighlight and Navigator components as well as a bunch of react-native tutorials. I can't seem to find any consistency - not even from the react-native docs.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  AsyncStorage,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

class PostAndSave extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messageTitle: '',
      messageBody: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Walker app
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Title"
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          onChange={(event) => this.setState({messageTitle: event.nativeEvent.text})}
          value={this.state.messageTitle} />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Body"
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          onChange={(event) => this.setState({messageBody: event.nativeEvent.text})}
          value={this.state.messageBody} />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>See all posts</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// styles here

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PostAndSave', () => PostAndSave);
```

I can type into the input fields but cannot figure AsyncStorage out, or how to post *new* messages as opposed to the overwriting the existing one. I'm mainly looking for help in that area - below I have posted my *goal* incase the question of why I want to do this comes up.

**Goal:**

The saved 'post' should then be printed to a view, where it can be pressed (tapped?) to display the contents of the body.

Each time a title and body are submitted they should be saved as a new 'post' and not overwritten.

Comment: async storage should work. whats are the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Async for this you'll need a function to save the data:

```
_onPressButton () {
  // Get the data
  let title = this.state.messageTitle
  let message = this.state.messageBody

  // Retrieve the existing messages
  AsyncStorage.getItem('messages', (res) => {
    var messages

    // If this is the first time, set up a new array
    if (res === null) {
      messages = []
    }else {
      messages = JSON.parse(res)
    }

    // Add the new message
    messages.push({
      title: title,
      message: message
    })

    // Save the messages
    AsyncStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(messages), (res) => {})
  }
}
```

And you'll want to bind this to your instance:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
```

And to retrieve your messages for use later:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('messages', (res) => {
  this.setState({
    messages: res
  })
})
```

Comment: Do we have a way to ensure a specific data type? I get the error `Entries must be arrays of the form [key: string, value: string], got: ( messages )` - I changed `undefined` to `null` when we set up the `messages` array because it wouldn't accept it otherwise. I now see my title and body inside a JSON error page... (it seems that it is expecting a specific string)... here is an additional error message after the JSON output: `NSMutableArray cannot be converted to NSString`

Comment: Ah yes, I've updated my answer - AS only takes strings, so you'll need to serialise/deserialise your data.

Comment: Thanks. This is great I didn't know about stringify. Also, for future readers, `if (res === undefined)` needs to be changed to `if (res === null)`